# Windows 10 Media Creation Tool not downloading (not using the internet)

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I have a Windows 8.1 Single Language 64-bit PC and I want to upgrade to Windows 10. Whenever I start the Media Creation tool, it gets internet (saw this on Windows Task Manager, BITS and this tool were getting internet), but as soon as the **"download"** part starts, it doesn't use any more internet and it is stuck a 0%.

So, my questions are -

1. How to enable Media Creation tool to get internet.
2. If this problem can't be solved, how should I download Windows 10 (I don't have it reserved and there is no **Download Windows 10** option in Windows Update).

**PS -** I have a metered connection but I have set it to non-metered option in Networks. And I have not downloaded all latest updates in Windows Update (running a limited internet) but I don't think these matter.

Comment: [A better solution then using GWXWebWindows.exe is to simply download the .ISO directly from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench).  Since an answer has already been accepted, I have no motivation, to post what I feel is a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a third party firewall, or otherwise are blocking outbound traffic either within Win 8 or at your router/firewall, it's possible that's what's blocking the Media Creation tool. On one of my PCs I had to temporarily allow ALL outbound traffic for it to work despite not getting any notifications of blocked traffic. It could also be blocked by anti-virus or other security software.

To get the "invite" message/app you do need have certain windows updates installed but those updates should NOT be required for the Media Creation tool to work. You will never see Win10 as just a regular Win8 update. I would disable whatever you can in terms of metering, temporarily allow all outbound traffic both in your PC and anywhere upstream, disable AV/security software, etc, and try starting here:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/8/0/C8007C4E-D1DD-4922-A966-3A927E86A033/GWXWebWindows.exe

Answer (score -1):

May be there is some problem with your Firewall or Internet connection or your isp blocked the site also another thing i saw happen us the antivirus extensions which don't let you use some sites which they think can be harmful so check this and if this doesn't work i think you should just copy it from someone.

Comment: How does the author fix those problems specifically?  This seems more like a comment then anything.

Answer (score -2):

I'm a bit of a leech who never comments but I have to now, because this is the only thing that works. --> Turn off your firewall, and the download will progress.

Comment: Already suggested in other answers